# C++ decltype, with if statement, for recursive function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, recursion, decltype

I'm trying to recursivly traverse my templated structure. 
To do this, I write recursive function get_my. It returns i-th element of chained my_pair's. 
*get_my* may be element Type, or pair type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


template<typename T0, typename T1>
struct my_pair{
    my_pair(T0 el0, T1 el1): el0(el0), el1(el1) {}
    T0 el0;
    T1 el1; // may be next pair
};

///
/// ERROR occurs here!
///
template<typename PairT>
auto get_my(PairT p, int i,  int current = 0) -> decltype( current == i ? p.el0 : p.el1 ){
    if (current == i){
        return p.el0;
    } else {
        return get_my(p.el1, i, current++);
    } 
}

template<typename T0, typename T1>
my_pair<T0, T1> make_my_pair(T0 el0, T1 el1){
    return my_pair<T0, T1>(el0, el1);
}



int main()
{
    my_pair<double, double> p1(12.789, 12.66);
    //auto p1 = make_my_pair(12.46, 12.66);
    //auto p2 = make_my_pair(p1, 12.66);

    auto el = get_my(p1, 0);
    cout<< el;
    return 0;
}
```

So... [the compilers says](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a96de73145bc64f3):

```
main.cpp:19:18: error: request for member 'el0' in 'p', which is of non-class type 'double'
         return p.el0;
                  ^
main.cpp:21:42: error: request for member 'el1' in 'p', which is of non-class type 'double'
         return get_my(p.el1, i, current++);
```

And I really don't understand why. It seems it try to traverse farther then it should.

Comment: You misuse the conditional ternary operator here. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other
Simply put, your expression may not have a well defined type for decltype to return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even when the compiler knows that the `else` block won't be entered, the code inside it must be syntactically valid. Consider what happens here when `p` is `double`:

```
if (current == i){
    return p.el0;
} else {
    return get_my(p.el1, i, current++);
}
```

`get_my` gets instantiated and inside it the compiler sees `return p.e10` with `Pair` being `double`.

The solution is overloading. Write another overload of `my_get` that stops the recursion when `Pair` is deduced for something else than `my_pair`. This can be done with [`enable_if` idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/enable-if) for example.

Even better, you could have an overload with `my_pair<T1, T2>` that recurses, and another general template that does not. No `enable_if` needed.

Comment: "Even better, you could have an overload with my_pair<T1, T2> that recurses" - What is return type than?

Comment: @tower120 `decltype(/* recursive call to my_get */)`, I suppose.

Comment: I still can't figure out how should I stop than. I still need that if.

Comment: @tower120 You're pretty much out of luck if you wish to have a different type based on a runtime number - that just doesn't work. If you can, make `i` a template parameter instead so you can select types based on it. Othwerwise you're stuck with the same type for `T0` for each nesting level. [Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77ab1e8f99caca35) an example, anyway.

Comment: i is compile time based, I move it to parameters, because I thought it will counts as constexpr, and all becomes preprocessed

Comment: I see. No, function parameters are not compile time constants even when initialized with literals.

Comment: @tower120 the return type of a function may not depend on the value of its parameters, even if those parameters are `constexpr`.  In your above example, the return type of the pair case is always the left most leaf type that isn't a pair.  It can depend on `template` value parameters, but not `constexpr` ones.  This may be because of ODR function unique name issues at the root.

Comment: @tower120 What Yakk said. See [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1acbd1bd15f4b135) and note the output `12` instead of `12.789`.

Comment: @jrok - that's because of my_pair<int ... you cast it to int on definition.

Comment: @Yakk - I say not about that it will return one type for BOTH values in pair. I say, that compiler removes loops, ifs, etc... And all comes down to a single preprocessed value. At least on -o1 level.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to specify the return type, based on `current == i ? type1 : type2` which is your issue.

The return type should be known in compile-time. In your case `decltype` is returning `double` as type, then you're trying to call `.el0` method of that primitive type.